# 500 internal server error with protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, csrf-protection

I'm building a JSON API in Rails 4 but I'm having trouble with CSRF authenticity check.
I've disabled it all together with:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

My `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_current_user!, only: [:login]

  def login
    username = params[:username]
    password = params[:password]

    begin
      @user = authenticate(username, password)
    rescue AuthenticationException
      render status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def logout
    log_out!
    render status: :success
  end
end
```

I can login correctly and my logout views renders as expected with correct output, but I'm still getting a `500 Internal Server Error`. My log says:

```
Started POST "/logout.json" for ::1 at 2016-01-18 12:17:04 +0100
Processing by UsersController#logout as JSON
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Rendered users/logout.json.jbuilder (0.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (Views: 7.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm expecting to get a `Completed 200 OK`.

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: Does your `UsersController` inherit from `ApplicationController` or from something else? (`DeviseController` perhaps)

Comment: I've got an `ApiController`, which inherit from `ApplicationController`, so it inherits `UsersController < ApiController < ApplicationController`, so yes.

Comment: I *think* you can (safely) solve this by skipping the filter only for the logout action. Add this to the `UsersController`: `skip_before_action :protect_from_forgery, only: :logout`.

Comment: @mtrolle Can you post little code snippets of users controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

In my `logout` method i call `render status: :success`

Combined with `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` this makes the actual status render to `500`.
But by removing `render status: :success` entirely from the `logout` function I now get `200` as expected.

I guess this must be a bug somewhere in Rails?

Comment: It turns out status :success doesn't exists in the first place: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html instead it's called :ok

Comment: it sure is confusing as hell when you have `assert_response :success` in the integration test codes :P I made the same mistake of using `:success` in place of `:ok`. I now refer to this chart: http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/10/13/list-of-rails-status-code-symbols/ for a list of Rails HTTP Status code symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Just skip the  CSRF authenticity check for the methods you don't want to,

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:logout]
```

Add the methods to which you don't want the CSRF authenticity check.